# Power on, power off voice using fx board

Tags: sound

I played with one of those Adafruit FX sound boards in a project a while ago, and see a lot of potential uses for it.
I would like to create “something” for my daughter, when she turns the lights on, (110v bedroom lights) a voice may say “good evening Kyndra” and when she turns the lights off the voice may say “have a good day...”.
The power “on” is not a big problem, the power off is my issue.... I could run a separate circuit and use a solid state off delay that when it sees first circuit go down it triggers a line of code. 
With all the new stuff coming out all the time, just wondering if anyone else has a better idea to build a poor mans version “Jarvis 1.0”.  Perhaps using an Arduino may not even be the route I want.

This is just a thought... I’ve been tossing over for a while now.  It’s not imperative it ever gets built. Just thought it would be cool for her.

Comment: A sufficiently large capacitor may give you enough time to play the sound after loss of power if you do a good job of detecting the event.  Best to do this downstream of an off-the-shelf mains supply rather than trying to make your own.

Comment: Just have it run on independent power, and detect if the lights go on/off by measuring the light level.